# Problemas de sql com disntinct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner

Tenho uma tabela na minha base de dados com:

- `horarioId`
- `horarioParagemId`
- `horarioLinhaId`
- `horarioHora`

Faço `INNER JOIN` da tabela linhas:

- `linhaId`
- `linhaNome`

Faço `INNER JOIN` da tabela paragens:

- `paragemId`
- `paragemRua`
- `paragemLatitude`
- `paragemLongitude`

  Exemplo da tabela horarios

HorarioId : 1
horarioParagemId : 3
horarioLinhaId : 4
horarioHora :22:00:00

HorarioId : 2
horarioParagemId : 3
horarioLinhaId : 4
horarioHora :21:00:00

O objectivo é só receber as coordenadas onde o id das paragens sejam diferentes. O código que eu fiz funciona com `paragemLatitude` ou `paragemLongitude`, mas não funciona com `paragemId`

```php
include_once('seguranca.php');
protegePagina();

$sql="SELECT DISTINCT horarioParagemId
      FROM horarios
      INNER JOIN paragens ON paragemId = horarioParagemId
      INNER JOIN linhas ON horarioLinhaId = linhaId
      WHERE horariolinhaId = " . $_GET['filtrapronto'];

$_SESSION['latitudefiltra']= array();
$_SESSION['longitudefiltra']= array();
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($dados=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $_SESSION['latitudefiltra'] [] = $dados['paragemLatitude'];
    $_SESSION['longitudefiltra'] []  = $dados['paragemLongitude'];
}

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Latitudes=$_SESSION['latitudefiltra'];
$obj->Longitudes=$_SESSION['longitudefiltra'] ; 
echo json_encode($obj);
```

Comment: Podes exemplificar o que resultado esperado?

Comment: É isso que você quer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5535ec/4 ?
Se não for, nos diga um exemplo de registros que você tem e qual resultado você espera.